# How to calculate the false positives and negatives?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, data-science, statistical-ai

I have a huge amount of data and I want to calculate my false positive and false negative. Is there a software that can help me determine it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `sklearn`'s [`confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html). To explicitly extract the false positives and negatives, you can do

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [1, 1, 1, 0]
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
```